# Powershell If else regex

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Wondering if someone could please suggest.

I've tried a few different ways to get the below working
The first piece of code I'm attempting to extract only the 5 digit number but end up with all property values.

The second I'm unable to get the else { 'No Extension Number' }  to output.

```
   #test for UM extension number#
   $um1 = Get-UmMailbox $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select @{name=”Extensions”;expression= 
   {$_.Extensions -join “;”}} | ?{ $_.Extensions -match '\d\d\d\d\d' }
   $umextensionnumber = if ($um1) { $um1 } else { 'No UM Extension Number' }

   #grab user attributes and test for extension number#
   $ad2 = Get-AdUser $user -Properties * | Select extensionAttribute10, msExchExtensionAttribute16, 
   @{name=”otherTelephone”;expression={$_.otherTelephone -join “;”}}
   $extensionnumber = if ($ad2) { $ad2.otherTelephone } else { 'No Extension Number' }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, anchor your regex pattern with `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string):

```bsh
... |? { $_.Extensions -match '^\d\d\d\d\d$' }
```

For the second one, assuming `otherTelephone` is the extension, change the `if` condition to check that property specifically:

```
$extensionnumber = if($ad2.otherTelephone){ $ad2.otherTelephone } else { "No Extension Number" }
```